# Java Swing - Using paintIcon in different class from JFrame one

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, imageicon

I'm making a little chess game and it has the classes `whitePawnPiece` that extends `whitePiece` that extends `chessMain` that extends `chessGUI`.

`chessGUI` is the `JFrame`, and `whitePawnPiece` is where I want to do `whitePawnIcon.paintIcon (...,...,xPos, yPos)`.

Well, first I don't understand very well the first 2 parameters, but from what I read the first can be `null` and the second should be the `JFrame`.

My question is: how do I use this second parameter? I'm using NetBeans and it accepts the first parameter as `null`, but the second, whatever I put, it gives an error "Cannot find symbol" or something.

PS: I was doing the GUI using NetBeans IDE but after reading the code I thought it was easier and better to program the GUI myself, so this is my first try at programming the GUI itself :)

And a bonus question: When I was using the NetBeans IDE I had some problems in overlaying images until I set the layout to Absolute (I was using labels to work with the icons). Will I have the same problem now or not? Should I use the default layout or there is a better one for a chess program that has lots of overlay (chessboard, pieces, selection/possible moves markers)?

Comment: _" I was doing the GUI using NetBeans IDE but after reading the code I thought it was easier and better to program the GUI myself, "_ - Good call :)

Comment: As a side note, use java naming convention. Class names begin with capital letters.

Comment: Also to have the `whiteChessPiece` have _all_ those ancestors, doesn't really make sense to me. I can see the `whitePeice`, but why the others? Doesn't seem like the greatest design. If you need to access instance variables from other class, don't expect inheritance to work. Just a hint.

Comment: @peeskillet I thought the convention was lowerCamelCase, must have confused with method naming convention hehe, ty! About the classes, I'm planning in overriding so each piece has the draw and move methods overriding from whitePiece, so I can make like whitePiece = whitePawnPiece and use move whitePiece

Comment: lower case is for variables. But yes, the camel casing in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little confusing, but...

`Icon` declares `paintIcon` as taking four parameters...

- `Component`
- `Graphics`
- `int x`
- `int y`

The is a reference to some component, presumably the one from which the `Graphics` context is associated with, as it's likely the the `Component` will be used as an `ImageObsever` to monitor changes to the icon when it needs to be updated and may provide other useful information

The `Graphics` context is actual place (the graphics output) where the image is to be painted.

Now, having said all that, in order to paint the icon successfully, you will need some kind of reference of some `Graphics` context.  This can be obtained by extending a component (like `JPanel`), overriding it's `paintComponent` method.  This will give you access to a `Graphics` context which can used to paint stuff in this paint cycle.  Never maintain a reference to a `Graphics` context you did not create yourself.

Then you would call `paintIcon` passing a reference to the component and the `Graphics` context.

Take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)

Having said all that, I think you will the use of `BufferedImage`s (or `Image`) simpler then `Icon`.  Take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

As to your second question.  No, you won't have the same issues, you'll have entirly brand new ones